# High ping on singapore servers

Tags: ping, latency

I have a PTCL fiber connection in my house and in the previous month i have seen that sometimes i used to get 120ms on singapore and sometimes 200ms but now i am getting 300+ ms. following is a tracert to a csgo singapore server.
can i get to know the way to get low ping because when i tested the ping on this server on my university internet (which is provided by NAYATEL) i was getting a solid 99ms.

```
  1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  182.176.0.122
  3     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.253.20.138
  4     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.4.1.5
  5     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.253.12.84
  6    29 ms    30 ms    29 ms  10.253.4.18
  7    26 ms    26 ms    26 ms  10.253.4.2
  8   340 ms   342 ms   342 ms  103.5.15.20
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12   337 ms   335 ms   337 ms  sin1-sgcs2-g1-nc5.sgp.asia [103.5.15.5]
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16   323 ms   321 ms   326 ms  sg-03.fragnet.net [139.99.125.28]
```

Comment: What DNS service are you using?

Comment: So PTCL Fiber means you’re in Pakistan, is that correct? Unless you are routed over one of the sea cables, that’s quite a lot of distance to Singapore.

Comment: i am using the default dns provided by my ISP 182.176.100.131

Comment: This needs to be escalated to the networking team with your internet broadband provider. There's nothing you can do about it on your end because those are the network cabinets that exist from street to street and area to area as your traffic passes from point A to point B. These boxes depending on which telecommunication companies own them could fall under multiple jurisdictions. Also, you might never know what the latency is of those boxes showing "Request Timeout" because these companies often disable their response to public ping requests for security purposes.